# Uniqueness of the remainder and quotient in an Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

> Let $R$ be a Euclidean ring with Euclidean norm $N$. Let $a,b\in R\setminus\{0\}$ and let $q,r\in R$  such that $a=bq+r$ with $r=0$ or $N(r)<N(b)$.
>   Prove that $r$ and $q$ are unique if and only if $N(a+b)\le\max\{N(a),N(b)\}$.

I do not see how to relate both.

If I suppose the second:
let $q'$ and $r'$ be  such that 
$a=bq'+r'$ with $r'=0$ or $N(r')<N(b)$

It is sufficient to prove that $r'=r$, because in this case $a=bq'+r'=bq+r$ implies $bq'=bq$ and then $q'=q$.

How $bq'+r'=bq+r$ then  $r'-r=b(q-q')$.

By the properties of Euclidian norm:
$$
N(r')-N(r)\le N(r)<N(b)
\quad\text{and}\quad
N(r-r')=N(b(q-q'))\ge N(b)
$$

I got other inequalities but I do not think they are any good.

For the converse I have no idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can assume that $N$ satisfies the property $N(a)\le N(ab)$ for all $a,b\in R\setminus \{0\}$ (for details check [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/euclideanrk.pdf)).
Using the above property it's easy to prove that $ N(x)=N (x') $ if $ x $ and $ x'$ are associates.

$\Longrightarrow$) We're going to prove it by contrapositive. Let's suppose that $N(a+b)>\max\{N(a),N(b)\}$, then $a+b\neq 0$ and so we can divide $a$ by $a+b$. We have $$a=(a+b)0+a$$ with $N(a)<N(a+b)$ and $$a=(a+b)1+(-b)$$ with $N(-b)=N(b)<N(a+b)$.

Therefore the quotient and the remainder are not unique.

$\Longleftarrow$) As you noted, it's enough to prove that $q=q'$ or $r=r'$. If $r=0$ or $r'=0$ the result follows immediately. So, from now on we assume that $r,r'\neq 0$ and we're going to prove that $q=q'$. If $r=r'$ we're done. Otherwise, let's suppose that $q\neq q'$. Since $b(q-q')=r'-r$ we have $$N(b)\le N(b(q-q'))=N(r'-r)=N(r-r')\le \max\{N(r),N(-r')\}<N(b).$$

So we got $N(b)<N(b)$, an absurd. Hence, it must be $q=q'$ and therefore $r=r'$.

$-------------------------------------$

The above result is used to characterize the euclidean domains having unique quotient and remainder. Check for example these papers:

i) [A Characterization of Polynomial Domains Over a Field](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2313196?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Tong-Shieng Rhai

ii) [Uniqueness in the Division Algorithm](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2315810?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by M. A. Jodeit, Jr.

Comment: Thank you and thank you also for editing my question.

Comment: @Edgar García you're welcome.

Comment: @Xam in $(\implies)$ you have showed that $N(a+b)>\max\{N(a),N(b)\}$ implies $q,r$ in $a=(a+b)q+r$ are not unique; but the question is asking us to prove: $N(a+b)>\max\{N(a),N(b)\}$ implies $q,r$ in $a=(b)q+r$ are not unique.

Comment: @Xam why $N(b)=N(-b)$?

Comment: @Hopmaths the norm of any associates are the same.